# Help with sage math defining function of two variables

Tags: sagemath

Hello I need help regarding sage math, since I cant find anything about it on the manuals.

So I have a function of the form $F(r,t) = 2r H(t)$  and then i want to perform an operation on it involving differentiation. H(t) is kept arbitrary. I know how to do this using sagemath. My question is, what if before performing any operation, I want to perform a change of variables $u = t-r$ and $v=t+r$ first? So my function now becomes

$F =(v-u) H( (u+v)/2)$

Is it possible to define H((u+v)/2) in sage math, such that when it takes the derivative it takes the partial derivative wrt u and then wrt v?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this is what you want](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxdTTsOAiEQ7U28Ax0z66hxe1rgGrsaDA2agZnzCyZu4nbv_3RhsI3Y4vEQjTNJyr3lVwEbLZmy8LO6G0Lrtu_2PPEUv-zNuTTjf-CRUwJPjHuBRljHi5COl9Bn_KXKWoEd6FnwOlNzICftaOuHv6FAgnuBFD-vfjWV&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

```
var('t,r')
H = function('H', nargs=1)(t)
F = 2*r*H(t)
print F
print diff(F,r)
print diff(F,r,t)
var('u,v')
G = F.subs(r=(v-u)/2,t=(u+v)/2)
print G
print diff(G,u)
print diff(G,u,v)
```

output:

```
2*r*H(t)
2*H(t)
2*diff(H(t), t)
-(u - v)*H(1/2*u + 1/2*v)
-1/2*(u - v)*D[0](H)(1/2*u + 1/2*v) - H(1/2*u + 1/2*v)
-1/4*(u - v)*D[0, 0](H)(1/2*u + 1/2*v)
```

You have to be careful with `F = 2*r*H(t)`, though, as it won't know what "order" the arguments come in.  `F(r,t) = ...` might work better there, but it will be weirder on the derivative side once you substitute because it will still think the "inputs" are `r,t`.

See `function?` for more documentation on how these abstract functions work, which isn't always intuitive.